# Javascript, I am using PDF kit to create pdf, and attached it to email, but sometimes pdf file in the email cannot open

Tags: javascript, pdfkit

I am using PDFkit with javascript to create pdf file and attached it to email.

When I received email, some pdf files can open ,some cannot. I guess that pdf files don't finish creation and then be attached to the email? My question is how to make sure that the pdf files are finished ? Thank you so much!

My code is shown below:

```
var doc;
var stream;
var attachmentList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sites.length; i++)　 {
    doc = new PDFDocument();

    doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('pdfStorage/' + sites[i].title.toString() + '.pdf'));
    doc.font('Calibri.ttf').fontSize(20)
        .text('PERFORMANCE REPORT for ' + sites[i].title.toString());

    doc.end();

    // Add to attachments
    attachmentList.push({
        path: './pdfStorage/' + sites[i].title.toString() + '.pdf',
    });
}
}

if (email) {
    //this is email information ;

}
```